# python logging fileConfig fileHandler args windows directory separator

Tags: python, logging

I seem unable to pass a logfile name with path to my logger on a windows platform using windows directory separators. Logger config:

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('%(logfilename)s',)
```

this works:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(logger_config_file, defaults={'logfilename': 'test.txt})
```

this works:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(logger_config_file, defaults={'logfilename': 'E:/dddd/rrrr/nnnn/tttt/test.txt'})
```

If I try:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(logger_config_file, defaults={'logfilename': 'E:\\dddd\\rrrr\\nnnn\\tttt\\test.txt'})
```

I get this exception:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\config.py", line 84, in fileConfig
handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\config.py", line 148, in _install_handlers
h = klass(*args)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1030, in __init__
StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1059, in _open
return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\dddd\rrrr\nnnn\tttt\test.txt'
```

I want to build this path using os.path.join. That will use "\\" windows directory separators. The code is supposed to run on windows and linux systems.

Am I supposed to put linux style separators into fileConfig, or is this a bug? What does a simple solution look like reformatting to linux style separators?
Thanks

Edit:

If I build the path like this, os.path.join() will add windows separators:

```
logging_path = os.path.join('E:/dddd/tttt', 'rrrr')
logging_file = os.path.join(logging_path, 'test.txt')
```

Resulting in: 'E:/dddd/tttt\\rrrr\\test.txt'

Which is a working path, because this works:

```
open(logging_file)
```

This will still fail:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(logger_config_file, defaults={'logfilename': logging_file})
```

I found a solution. This works:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(logger_config_file, defaults={'logfilename': logging_file.replace('\\', '/'})
```

I am not sure if I should have known not to put Windows separators into fileConfig or if fileConfig could have handled that better. Anyway I hope this might help somehow.

Comment: Have you tried with 'E:\dddd\\rrrr\\nnnn\\tttt\\test.txt' ? you need \\r because \r is special character, \n and \t also but not \d

Comment: Correct the problem seems to be connected to the special characters. But if I use os.path.join() or os.path.normpath() i have no control over the separator. The fileConfig constructor messes the path string up, so the open(...) fails. I am wondering why and if that is expected behaviour.

Comment: Sorry did not really understand "i have no control over the separator" could you edit your question to make it clearer. I also did not understand if trying 'E:\dddd\\rrrr\\nnnn\\tttt\\test.txt' solved the issue.